# Can Instant WordPress be used on a network drive?

Tags: php

I'm trying to put a site that I've just built onto my companies internal server so that everyone at the company can see the site and give feedback. However, I tried to install both WAMP and Instant WordPress on the network drive, which is a Windows server, I believe. Unfortunately, neither of them will run when I try to start them.

Is there a way to install Instant WordPress on a network drive?

Comment: yes.... have you mapped the drive?

Comment: I hadn't mapped the drive and that seems to have gotten it going. I can't believe I didn't know that, but I haven't worked with local servers much before.

Comment: Hi, I just want to ask one more question regarding this. Is there a way to send the location of the mapped network drive (folder) in an email? The easy way to do this would just be for others to map the same network drive, but my boss doesn't like to do things the easy way. @bybe

Comment: Create an intranet.

Comment: I wish I could create anything. I've resorted to rebuilding the site in html for the local server and storing anything that needs php offsite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually with Windows Server versions, ports 80 and 8080 are reserved for IIS (this is assuming you're using Windows Server 20XX. If you're not, and you're using Windows 7/8/8.1, the rest may be unnecessary). Your options for getting your WordPress install to work are either to install PHP for IIS and use the IIS manager to run your WordPress install (which can be a pain in the you-know-what to configure... from my experience, IIS doesn't like PHP very well, but that could have been improved over the last 10 years or so) or to redirect ports 80 and 8080 (as well as HTTPS port 443 and your SSL port, if necessary) to WAMP/XAMPP/Instant WordPress via the Windows Firewall.

The last option (and the one I use if I happen to be using a Windows server and need to build a test PHP environment) is a little more advanced. You would need to configure the apache server for WAMP/XAMPP/Instant WordPress to listen for a different port, such as 8081 (or any port number you choose, so long as it's not already being used by another program / protocol), and point port 8081 incoming and outgoing to Apache. Then you would access the site via http://localhost:8081/ or http://your.fqdn:8081/ or http://192.168.1.199:8081/ (replace that IP with your server's IP). If you need to access your WP site outside of your subnet, you would also need to apply port forwarding to your server's IP in your router / DNS.